# Gujrati font Rendering problem in Flutter PDF

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, multilingual

I am Developing a Mobile application using Flutter 2.0, this whole application is in the Gujarati language, the application is ready, all text is rendering perfectly in the app, but when I generate pdf from data that are on the screen, the Gujarati fonts not rendering correctly,

I am using plugin

> pdf: ^3.0.1

for Ex,

there is the string on-screen is ***લોગિન***
and when I print in pdf it becomes ***લોગનિ***

Same for another ***ઉત્સવ*** becomes ***ઉત્ સવ***(*ignore space between words*)

Comment: i have same issue on multi language(en,gu) print.
you have find any solution ?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this flutter library

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf#create-a-pdf-document-from-simple-text

```
//Create a new PDF document.
final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
//Read font data.
final Uint8List fontData = File('arial.ttf').readAsBytesSync();
//Create a PDF true type font object.
final PdfFont font = PdfTrueTypeFont(fontData, 12);
//Draw text using ttf font.
document.pages.add().graphics.drawString('Hello World!!!', font,
    bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 200, 50));
// Save the document.
File('TrueType.pdf').writeAsBytes(document.save());
// Dispose the document.
document.dispose();
```